# Running both 32 and 64 bit version of Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, internet-explorer-11

I need to be able to select which version of IE11 I run (32 or 64 bit) on my 64-bit Windows 7.

I've tried running it from "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)", but the "bittnes" is always the same. If Enhanced Protected Mode is enabled IE always runs in 64-bit, if it is disabled IE will always run in 32-bit mode.

Comment: What is your question?  The method you are using is how you do it.

Comment: @Ramhound The method does not work :-)

Comment: Which method your method which you indicated does work or the possible duplicate method which I have verified still works with IE11 on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you read the non-checkmark answer by Karan on the possible duplicate?

Comment: Yeah, I kinda managed to get get to the same conclusion as Karan's explanation. The problem is, I'd like to run my SilverLight app in both versions to test it. And setting Enhanced Protected Mode requires restart (and I've done some of those already today), And I have to (un)set it to force my app to run in 32/64-bit mode. And since I'm new to the project and SilverLight, I was aiming for a quick fix.

Comment: @Luc - Use a virtual machine.  Microsoft provides trial virtual machines with every possible combination of Windows and IE possible.